# How to validate/ignore optional value while validating it using 'Validate CSV' processor in Apache NiFi?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi, jython

I'm new to Apache Nifi Community and I got stuck at one point - please help me for the below problem :

In Validate CSV processor I'm giving below schema(**schema_used**) to validate the CSV input. But, processor is showing error(**err_screenshot**).

**Validate CSV** - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMuet.png)

**Schema_Used** - *StrNotNullOrEmpty(), ParseDate("MM/dd/yyyy"), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), Optional(), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), Optional(), Optional(), StrNotNullOrEmpty()*

The above schema is showing below error -
**err_screenshot** - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAGYP.png)

**Note:** The Schema is working totally fine, if I remove 'Optional()'.

**Problem** - Please tell me how can I use 'Validate CSV' processor in Apache Nifi and validate Mandatory/Optional Fields of CSV. Also, suggest/share any script(groovy/python) if that can validate the CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check documentation: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.25.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ValidateCsv/additionalDetails.html

> Schema property: Null, ParseDate("dd/MM/yyyy"), Optional(ParseDouble())
> Meaning: the input CSV has three columns, the first one can be null and has no specification, the second one must be a date formatted as expected, and the third one must a double or null (no value).

You can't use empty cell processors `Optional()`.

I don't see input CSV data, so I can only suggest that could solve your problem:

`StrNotNullOrEmpty(), ParseDate("MM/dd/yyyy"), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), Optional(StrNotNullOrEmpty()), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), StrNotNullOrEmpty(), Optional(StrNotNullOrEmpty()), Optional(StrNotNullOrEmpty()), StrNotNullOrEmpty()`